# AHK script for a timed autofire function

Tags: timer, toggle, autohotkey, repeat

Goal of the script: to continually press Numpad0 for 10 seconds each time hotkey is pressed.

Current code:

```
toggle = 0
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

timerToggle:
Toggle := !Toggle
sleep 10000
Toggle := !Toggle

F12::
        SetTimer, timerToggle, -1
     While Toggle{
        send {NumPad0}
        sleep 100
    }
return
```

At present, the script will run as intended, but only once. Attempting to run it again after the first time does nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script likely doesn't toggle your variable correctly.  Here is a cleaner version of what you are trying to do which uses `A_TickCount`:

```
F12::SetTimer, HoldNumPad, -1

HoldNumPad:
    kDown := A_TickCount
    While ((A_TickCount - kDown) < 10000)
    {
        Send {Numpad0}
        Sleep 100
    }
Return
```

Note that pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> while the label is running will not have any affect.

EDIT: Made SetTimer use `-1` period to run only once, thanks to MCL.

Comment: Although technically equivalent, I find it cleaner to call `SetTimer, HoldNumPad, -1` instead of deactivating it later. It saves you a line of code and regarding the hotkey, it's more readable.

Comment: I actually was not familiar with the negative period! A quick search of the documentation beforehand didn't yield `-1`.  Looks like it is listed as `Run only once` instead. I'll edit and make note.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit hidden. Thinking about it again made me realise that using `-1`, it also runs instantaneously instead of the default 250 ms timeout when you don't specify a parameter...

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use `SetTimers` instead of a 10 sec. long `while` like so

```
F12::
Send {Numpad0}
SetTimer, start, 100
SetTimer, stop, -10000
return

start:
Send {Numpad0}
return

stop:
SetTimer, start, off
return
```